# Unable to let Sentry filters work properly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I'm still getting used to Sentry, but if I'm correct I'm doing things right.

The thing is, when I apply a filter to a route, it doesn't work the way I'd like it to do. It's supposed to check if the user is logged in, if it is *not* logged in, redirect him/her to the login page.

The way I'm logging users in:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $credentials = array(
        'username' => $this->input->get('email_or_username'),
        'password' => $this->input->get('password')
    );
    try
    {
        $user = $this->sentry->authenticate($credentials, false);
        if ($user)
        {
            return $this->redirect->route('user.dashboard.index');
        }
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return $this->redirect->route('login')->withErrors(array('login' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Should be OK right? Next I got my route (I only grouped it to test the filter on this specific route resource):

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'Sentry'), function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserProfileController',
        array('names' =>
            array(
                'index'=>'this.user.index',
                'create'=>'this.user.create',
                'store'=>'this.user.store',
                'show'=>'this.user.show',
                'edit'=>'this.user.edit',
                'update'=>'this.user.update',
                'destroy'=>'this.user.destroy'
            )
        )
    );
    // (index)show your profile info, (edit,update)Edit and update your profile 
});
```

And at last the filter which is supposed to check the user, and redirect if he/she is not logged in:

```
Route::filter('Sentry', function()
{
    if (!Sentry::check()){
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }
});
```

I've been stuck on this for a few days now, I've asked many other people to take a look at it, and they all say the same: "Well, thats odd...". So, I hoped someone here could give me some input on this.

Comment: whats the problem? Does it fail to login the user? or is the filter failing to redirect unauthenticated user? or something else? please do clarify your question further.